# Issue compiling Chicken files in Geiser/Emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, chicken-scheme, geiser

I installed Geiser in Emacs. In a scheme buffer, if I run `C-c C-s`, I can choose Chicken as the implementation. If I run `C-c C-z`, it starts an REPL and switches to it. My buffer seems to be correctly linked to the REPL. However, if I hit `C-c C-c` on a function definition, nothing is happening. Going to the REPL and calling my function fails (unbound variable). `C-c C-c` is bound to `geiser-eval-definition`.

What am I missing in my setup?